# Plot big data set on leaflet map [ Loading issue ]

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I want to show geo data (Buildings) of a city. I have a huge data set(400 mb), I can't load all the data at once. In order to solve this issue, I am working to load only data on the interval I am seeing.

My get data set is like that,

```
var data3d = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [13.37356, 52.52064],
                [13.37350, 52.51971],
                [13.37664, 52.51973],
                [13.37594, 52.52062],
                [13.37356, 52.52064]
            ]]
        },
        "properties": {
            "wallColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "height": 500
        }
    }]
};
```

I load data to the map this way

```
new L.BuildingsLayer().addTo(map).geoJSON(data3d);
```

I need to fetch data from json file and add to map, by developing  pan events and get new buildings data

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
    getBuildings();
});
```

Any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: Search google, googleMapsAPI , EarthQuake Data, this will have a json loading example *be sure* that your Json data is valid , else your map will be grey - loading Json that is malformed does not through an error (just a tip for you)

Comment: This will run into the problem of zooming out, or zooming everywhere and loading all the data. Use [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/), [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/), or another solution that does data better, or simplify your data until it's a more reasonable size.

Comment: what about streaming json data ? how efficient is this method